# How can I change the language of the keyboard shortcuts of Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change office shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/220247/how-to-change-office-shortcuts)

Hi guys, I'm running Word 2010 in Portuguese. My problem is that all shortcuts are in portuguese, while I'm used to the english-based shortcuts. Is there a way to set all shortcuts to english-based?

The only "solution" that I found is modify (by hand) each shortcut one at time. I hope this isn't the best solution.

Comment: I guess this is not possible. The only solution is to install the English version.

Comment: If you mark this question as duplicate then please make a link to the answer.

Comment: If it is not possible to standardize keyboard shortcuts across language versions then please make it possible. This is a highly desired feature in a globalized world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I just installed the Spanish version of Office 2010 - big mistake as I now have the same problem as you. As far as I can see the keyboard shortcuts go with the UI (ribbon, menus) language. If you want English shortcuts you must install the English UI. The only way for you now to get the English UI is to purchase an English language pack.

If you (theoretically) start from zero, you have three options if you want to use English shortcuts:

1. Purchase Office in English. You get the UI in English and proofing tools (spellchecker etc) for English, French and Spanish. If that's all you need, problem solved!
2. Purchase Office in English and then purchase a language pack for your language.
3. Purchase Office in your language and then purchase an English language pack.

Both options 2 and 3 will give you the ability to set the UI into English, and use the proofing tools for various other languages. See the [proofing tools you get with a language](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/language/office-2010-suites-localized-versions-HA101828838.aspx). You are only able to set the UI into the primary language of the Office edition or language packs you have.

Comment: Posting *identical* answers for different questions is unusual behaviour, and if there is a valid reason to do this it normally means the questions are duplicates of one-another (as per me closing this question), so next time can you please flag the duplicate for a moderator to come and close as appropriate...