# Keyboard shortcuts in non-English version of Microsoft Office

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, language

I have a big problem with the Portuguese version of MS Office 2007 and 2010.

The standard shortcuts that any common application uses are changed.
Some shortcuts that are not working: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (save), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (find) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (select all).

I want to configure it to use the shortcuts of the English version.

There is an option that allow to configure each shortcut separately. Furthermore, I have to configure for each app, if I configure in Word, I will have to configure again for Excel.

How to use the shortcuts of the English version of MS Office regardless of the Office language?

Thanks

Comment: Same here!! Same language also. LOL. I'm thinking in installing the EN version and then add the Language pack for dictionary. Have you tried it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change office shortcuts?](http://superuser.com/questions/220247/how-to-change-office-shortcuts)

Comment: In the italian version to save we need to presst ctrl+B, this is so annoying...

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost certain that there's not built-in way to change shortcuts in MS Office applications.

However, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) for this purpose.

#### The script

```
^a::
^f::
^s::
    WinGet, Process, ProcessName, A
    if(RegExMatch(Process, "^(WINWORD|EXCEL)\.EXE$"))
    {
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^a")
           SendPlay, ^e
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^f")
           SendPlay, ^b
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^s")
           SendPlay, ^g
    }
    else
        SendPlay, %A_ThisHotKey%
return
```

#### How it works

- `^a::`, specifies one of the hotkeys that run the script before the `return` statement, where `^` indicates the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
- `WinGet, Process, ProcessName, A` stores the active (`A`) window's process name in the variable `Process`.
- `if(RegExMatch(Process, "^(WINWORD|EXCEL)\.EXE$")) {...} else ...` checks if `Process`  matches the [regular expression](http://regular-expressions.info), i.e., if it matches one of the strings `WINWORD.EXE` or `EXCEL.EXE`.

  - If so, the first block gets executed.

    - `if(A_ThisHotKey = "^a")` checks if the pressed hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

      If it is, it simulates the key bombination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, which is the Portuguese hotkey to select all<sup>1</sup>.
  - Otherwise, `SendPlay, %A_ThisHotKey%` simulates the key combination that was initially pressed.

    This way, other applications still behave as they should.

#### How to use

1. [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install the latest version of AutoHotkey.
2. Save the above script as `ms-office.ahk`, using your favorite text editor.
3. Double-click the file to run the script.
4. If you wish, copy the script (or a link to it) in the `Startup` folder.
5. To add further MS Office applications, just modify the regular expression.

   To add PowerPoint, e.g., replace `(WINWORD|EXCEL)` by `(WINWORD|EXCEL|POWERPNT)`.
6. To add further hotkeys, you have to modify two parts of the script.

   To add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Open...), e.g., add the line `^o::` to the list at the very top add these lines inside the `if` block:

   ```
   if(A_ThisHotKey = "^o")
       SendPlay, ^a
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, I **think** it is. I took the hotkeys from my Spanish MS Office. Adjust if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer, a couple more shortcuts (could be added to the previous answer):

```
^a::
^f::
^s::
^w::
^n::
^u::
^d::
^r::
^b::
^i::
^k::
^g::
    WinGet, Process, ProcessName, A
    if(RegExMatch(Process, "^(EXCEL)\.EXE$"))
    {
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^a") ;seleccionar rango
           SendPlay, ^e
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^f") ;buscar
           SendPlay, ^b
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^s") ;guardar
           SendPlay, ^g
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^w") ;cerrar
           SendPlay, ^r
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^n") ;nuevo libro
           SendPlay, ^u
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^u") ;subrayar
           SendPlay, ^s
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^b") ;negrita
           SendPlay, ^n
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^i") ;cursiva
           SendPlay, ^k
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^d") ;filldown
           SendPlay, ^j
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^r") ;fill right
           SendPlay, ^d
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^k") ;hyperlink
           SendPlay, ^!k
       if(A_ThisHotKey = "^g") ;goto
           SendPlay, ^i
    }
    else
        SendPlay, %A_ThisHotKey%
return
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is already 8 years old. Since then, there is a simpler alternative, as Microsoft released its Office's language packs for free.

**Note:** although this is a simple and clean approach, it has the side effect of also changing Office's interface (menus and dialog boxes) to English.

You can download the language packs for Office 2016, Office 2013 and Office 2010 in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f). Download and install the language pack for English, then execute the steps described in the download page to configure MS Office's display language. After a restart, the English shortcuts should be in effect.

Obs.: Initially I had some bugs after the language pack installation. That's because I installed a 64-bit language pack over my 32-bit Office. After correcting the problem, my MS Office is working as expected.